# Some things are wrong with file obj when exporting (Forge API)

Tags: .net-core, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

When I translate file RVT to Obj, which I import to software to view file Obj. I get a problem, Axis Z now becomes Axis Y or  Axis Z now becomes Axis X and the opposite. I sometimes use file obj, so I don't know if it's correct, or if my app has a problem when exporting file obj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed. I encountered the exact same problem. I explained one way to solve it in the article on [Flipping OBJ Axes and OBJ Texture for Forge](https://the3dwebcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/06/flipping-obj-axes-with-texture-for-forge-viewer.html). I hope that helps.